# Is there any tool to parse a text with Regex and save to a Database the capturing group?

Tags: database, regex

I've to face the following challenge which I would like to automatize using a Regular Expression tool:

I have to match this two mappings:

1. `GetSQLParameter("@switch", SqlDbType.TinyInt, 1), _
   GetSQLParameter("@IDUtente", SqlDbType.Int), _`
2. `sqlClient.AddParameterWithValue("switch", SqlDbType.TinyInt, user.IDUser);
   sqlClient.AddParameterWithValue("IDUtente", SqlDbType.Int, user.IDUser);`

I would like to use 2 capturing group on the first code to get the name of the parameter and it's DB type.

Then I would like to analyze the second piece of code matching the name of the parameter and it's DB Type just to replace it.

Is there a tool for making this kind of matching?

I've asked a strongly related question on Stack Overflow: [Which solution to parse a text with Regex and save to a Database the capturing group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539695/which-solution-to-parse-a-text-with-regex-and-save-to-a-database-the-capturing-g)

Comment: I'm not aware of a tool specifically for Regex that persists to a database but you could probably achieve this with [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and a bit of .net code (C#, VB or F#).

Comment: [Please do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). This question isn't exactly the same as [your question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539695/which-solution-to-parse-a-text-with-regex-and-save-to-a-database-the-capturing-g), but it's strongly related. In this case, please link the questions to each other, so that people don't end up redoing the work of writing answers that are already present on the other site.

Comment: @Gilles: ok, I will do in this way the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pentaho Data Integration](http://community.pentaho.com/projects/data-integration/) (PDI) (aka Kettle) can easily do this.

You will need to start a new transformation, start with one of the input steps to import your data, then use the [Regex Evaluation](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Regex+Evaluation) scripting step to "Create fields for capture groups," and finally use the Table Output (or Insert / Update) step to write the data out to the database.

[image]